# convert to string to array in ruby or javascript to be in used in an SQL query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to convert a string to an array either in ruby on rails or in javascript or even jquery.

In my code, i get the values of the strings from a select option. So on option selected, i capture this value which returns the string

```
var lenders = $(this).val();
```

This is the string it returns. Just a line of id numbers separated by commas
`"15,16,17"` and i want to convert it to an array like this `[15, 16, 17]` either in ruby or in javascript.

How do i achieve this?

I have tried doing

```
"15,16,17".split(',')
```

i have also tried doing `"15,16,17".to_a`

but all to no avail

Answer (score 2):

`"15,16,17".split(',').map(&:to_i)` would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

**For Ruby** ..........

```
"15,16,17".split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

**For Javascript** .....

```
var string = "15,16,17";
var array = JSON.parse("[" + string + "]");
console.log(array)
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
"1,2,3,4".split(",").map {|s| s.to_i }
```

Comment: It's not a valid ruby syntax.

Comment: yes, this is valid, but it's the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/38185919/2057388